# No array filter found for identifier '-1'

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I am developing a .NET application with MongoDB, using C# driver 2.14.
My query is as follows:

I have an embedded array elements, eg:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
        "Friends" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "FirstName" : "Bob",
                        "LastName":"Marley",
                        "Gender":"Male",
                        ...
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "Name" : "Jonson",
                        "LastName":"Charles",
                        "Gender":"Male",
                        ...
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 4,
                        "Name" : "Bob",
                        "LastName":"",
                        "Gender":"Male",
                        ...
                }
        ]
}
```

which has multiple fields in it. I need to update all the values in one of the nested documents.

I have written a code as follows:

```cs
var filter1 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", 1);
var filter2 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch<BsonValue>("Friends", new BsonDocument(){ {"_id", 2 }});

var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Friends.$[-1]", BsonDocument.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)));

await collection.UpdateAsync(filter1&filter2, update);
```

I am getting the exception as:

> No array filter found for identifier '-1'

Can anyone please suggest whether it's the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an invalid syntax/statement in MongoDB for

```
"Friends.$[-1]"
```

You need [arrayFilter](https://database.guide/how-the-arrayfilters-parameter-works-in-mongodb/) to update document in the nested array field.

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;

var filter1 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", 1);
var filter2 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch<BsonValue>("Friends"
    , new BsonDocument() { { "_id", 2 } });

// Sample value to be updated
var obj = new
{
    _id = 2,
    FirstName = "Bobby",
    LastName = "Marley",
    Gender = "Female"
};

var arrayFilters = new[]
{
    new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(
        new BsonDocument("friend._id", 2)
        )
};

var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Friends.$[friend]", obj.ToBsonDocument());

await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter1 & filter2, update,
    options: new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = arrayFilters });
```

**Note:**

This statement is used to convert `object` to `BsonDocument`.

```cs
BsonDocument.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object))
```

can be replaced with

```cs
obj.ToBsonDocument()
```

---

> Output

[image]

[image]